# Understanding the Ruby sort_by method in a simple histogram

Tags: ruby

While chugging along over at Codecademy, I ran into a bit of confusion with the `sort_by` method.

For example, what is happening with the `{ |a, b| b }` in my code? I imagine `|a, b|`, or whatever you want it to be designated as, maps the `|key, values|` of an array, but what does it mean then to sort my new Hash `frequencies` by `{ |key, value| value }`?

```
puts "Let's make a histogram of word counts, please supply text: "
text = gets.chomp

words = text.split(" ")
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
words.each { |word| frequencies[word] += 1 }
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by { |a, b| b }
frequencies.reverse!
frequencies.each { |word, frequency| puts word + " " + frequency.to_s }
```

Comment: You sort key-value pairs by value. What's the question, again?

Comment: Your title doesn't make sense, considering that a histogram is a graphical representation of data. I suggest you change "in a simple histogram" to "when counting frequencies" (or some-such).

Answer (score 0):

`Hash#sort_by{|key, value| value}` (actually defined as `Enumerable#sort_by`) means:

- Take `key` and `value` to be the key and the value of each key-value pair (This much indicated by `|key, value|`), and
- Sort by `value` (This much indicated by `value`).

Comment: It's Enumerable#sort_by, btw

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Right. But in this case, I have to particularly tell that the variables correspond to the key and the value.

Answer (score 0):

When you sort a hash, you always provide two variables, in this case, `a` and `b`, which, like you said, represent the key and the value. When you only sort by the second variable, it means you want to sort your hash based solely on the value.

In your example, when you sort by value and then reverse it, you are sorting your frequencies in order of most frequent to least frequent word.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_hash = {
  "a" => 2,
  "b" => 3,
  "c" => 1
}

some_hash.sort_by { |key, value| value }
```

Which returns

```
[["c", 1], ["a", 2], ["b", 3]]
```

The `sort_by` method will sort based on a conditional you pass it in the block. So I could've done something like:

```
some_hash.sort_by { |key, value| key.start_with?("a") && value > 0 }
```

and this would return any key/value pair that meets those conditions.

Also, you can use `sort_by` with only one argument:

```
sort_by { |arg| arg }
```

Passing two arguments in the pipes allows you to separate the key and values in the hash and sort each of the pairs by the condition you set.